# SQL Select (only names of those that fulfill all the search conditions)

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a task that says that I must select all firstnames and lastnames of students that are attending course1 and not attending course3...ONLY THOSE WHO CORRESPORD TO THOSE REQUIREMENTS. How can I select that and present it in relational algebra? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share your tables' structures

Comment: Show that you attempted something

Comment: `SELECT fname, lname FROM students WHERE course1 = 'Y' AND course3 = 'N'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database has a table where the student and their classes are related.
use minus to find the students you want:

```
SELECT fname, lname FROM YOURTABLE WHERE course = 'Course1'
minus
SELECT fname, lname FROM YOURTABLE WHERE course = 'Course3'
```

In this way, students are included in the result if they are in course1, and are excluded from the result if they are in course3. You are left with students who are in course1 and not in course3

My guess is that the relational algebra looks like this:

```
∏ fname, lname ( σ course = "course1" (YOURTABLE) ) - ∏ fname, lname ( σ course = "course3" (YOURTABLE) )
```

Comment: How can I present it in relational algebra?

Answer (score 0):

For as general as this is...

```
SELECT firstName, lastName 
FROM classTbl
WHERE courseNo = course1
AND courseNo <> course3
```